# US Population Hypothesis Test

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset, demography

I’m hoping someone can give me some tips on the test I have in mind for my data. I have data which is samples of Americans from various zip codes throughout the US.  In my data I assume if someone has the same first name, last name, date of birth, sex, and zip code then they are the same person, but the records in my data don’t have a unique identifiers so I can’t be certain.  I plan to compare my sample data to the US population in general.

My thought is to calculate the rate of unique people with those matching demographics in the general population and compare it to my assumed rate of 0 in my sample data using a hypothesis test, maybe like t-test and see if the p-value indicates I should reject the null hypothesis that the rate of unique people with those matching demographics in the general US population is 0.
Does my logic sound correct or can anyone suggest a better test for the data.

Comment: "Does anyone know where I could get that data on the US population" - questions on data sets are off-topic here, but there is e.g. [Open Data SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/). If you edit your question, though, I think your query about testing ought to be on-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the tip about Open Data SE

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you must think if going to all this trouble is worth it -- i.e. would the violation of your uniqueness assumption drastically affect your end result?  This obviously depends highly on what you are using the data for.  A little background on uniqueness of personal identification data can be found here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3032399/, but in general it is thought that about 80% of adults in the US can be uniquely identified based on date of birth, sex, and zip code alone.  I think it is fairly safe to assume that based on that number, the chances of having the same name and other demographic info is highly unlikely.  But again, if there is a small violation, will this affect your end result?

Comment: (+1) 80% is interesting. As a reality check, the US population is near 300 million, approximately evenly distributed by day of birth and sex. That's 410,000 of each sex per day of year, so perhaps about 1/50 of them--about 8000--will fall into the most populous age bracket. There are c. 40,000 zip codes (quick check: there are only 100,000 possible five-digit codes and many of them are used). A random assignment of date of birth to zip code--which is a crude approximation--implies the counts per zip code are Poisson(8/40), giving a 90% chance of being uniquely identified. 80% is reasonable!

Comment: @whuber I love it! That was a great back of the envelope calculation!

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help to allay your fears is to consider standard policies for [data de-identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-identification).  That is, when a dataset (e.g., a medical dataset with patient records, tests, disease states, treatments, etc.) is going to be made publicly available, it first has to be de-identified so that protected health information cannot be connected to a person.  People often assume that if you remove things like the patient's name, social security number, etc., that will be adequate to de-identify data, but that is not true.  A standard policy is that data are identifiable if they include, e.g., full birth date, sex, and zip code.  The probability of two people with the same sex and birthday living in the same zip code is sufficiently small that you can safely assume the record and the person are the same<sup>1</sup>.  I note that you have all of that, in addition to first and last name, so you certainly have enough information now.

<sub>1. Sweeney, Latanya. Simple demographics often identify people uniquely. Carnegie Mellon University, 2000. http://dataprivacylab.org/projects/identifiability/paper1.pdf

 (copied from Wikipedia: [*Quasi-identifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-identifier), footnote 2.)</sub>